# How to add a new row and new column to a multiindex Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use `.loc` to create a new row and a new column to a multiindex Pandas dataframe, by specifying all the axis. The problem is that it creates the new index without the new column, and at the same time throws an obscur `KeyError: 6`.

How could I do that ? A one line solution whould be much appreciated.

```
> df
                   side    total    value
city   code type                             
NaN    NTE  urban  ouest   0.01949  391.501656

> df.loc[(np.nan, 'NTE', 'rural'), 'population'] = 1000
KeyError: 6

> df
                   side    total    value
city   code type                             
NaN    NTE  urban  ouest   0.01949  391.501656
NaN    NTE  rural    NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Now, when I try the same command again it complains the index doesn't exist.

```
> df.loc[(np.nan, 'NTE', 'rural'), 'population'] = 1000
KeyError: (nan, 'NTE', 'rural')
```

The desired output would be this dataframe:

```
                   side    total    value        population
city   code type                             
NaN    NTE  urban  ouest   0.01949  391.501656          NaN
NaN    NTE  rural    NaN       NaN         NaN         1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is problem with missing values, possible hack solution with assign empty string and `rename`:

```
df.loc[('', 'NTE', 'rural'), 'population'] = 1000
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(nan, 'NTE', 'urban'),
            ( '', 'NTE', 'rural')],
           names=['city', 'code', 'type'])

df = df.rename({'':np.nan}, level=0)

print (df.index)

MultiIndex([(nan, 'NTE', 'urban'),
            (nan, 'NTE', 'rural')],
           names=['city', 'code', 'type'])

print (df)
                  side    total       value  population
city code type                                         
NaN  NTE  urban  ouest  0.01949  391.501656         NaN
          rural    NaN      NaN         NaN      1000.0
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like there is no need to rename. The new index 0 is allocated with `NaN` directly.

Comment: @Florent - Added `print (df.index)` for see difference